# How to use assertSequenceEqual with pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, python-unittest

I want to to check whether two `pandas.Series` objects have the same contents using the `unittest` module:

```
    self.assertSequenceEqual(
        df['some_column'],
        someOtherSeries)
```

According to the `unittest` documentation the above should work (based on [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertSequenceEqual)). However, when I run my above unit test I get this:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_my_test (my_module.test.test_my_module.SimpleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/src/my_module/my_module/test/test_my_test.py", line 28, in test_my_test
    someOtherSeries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 663, in assertSequenceEqual
    if seq1 == seq2:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 917, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I test whether to Series are the same?

Note that converting the Series to `list` objects seem to get around this problem, but it feels like a hack:

```
    self.assertSequenceEqual(
        list(df['some_column']),
        list(someOtherSeries))
```

Comment: Do you want to check if the values are equal, or that the values *and* indexes are equal? (Converting to lists only checks that the values are equal.)

Comment: @unutbu just the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `df['some_column'].values` is a `numpy` array. To *test* equality (o equivalence) of `numpy` arrays, you can use [`numpy.testing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.testing.html):

```
from numpy import testing

testing.assert_array_equal(df['some_column'].values, someOtherSeries.values)
```

If the arrays are floating points, you should consider [`numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal.html)

```
testing.assert_almost_equal(df['some_column'].values, someOtherSeries.values)
```

as directly equating floating point numbers is problematic.

Comment: Note that an assertion is not well suited for unittest. I think using `numpy.array_equal` in the following way makes sense: `self.assertTrue(numpy.array_equal(df['some_column'].values, someOtherSeries.values))`